# Strange NetCDF file with Lat / Long as 2D dimensions?

Tags: gdal, netcdf, panoply

I have this NetCDF file from Germany DWD: https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/daily/Project_TRY/air_temperature_mean/TT_201001_daymean.nc.gz

However, I don't know why this netCDF has **Lat** and **Lon** axes in 2D.

```
double lon(y, x) ;
double lat(y, x) ;
```

The result from **ncdump** is below:

```
ncdump -h TT_20100101_daymean.nc 
netcdf TT_20100101_daymean {
dimensions:
    x = 720 ;
    y = 938 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (31 currently)
    bnds = 2 ;
variables:
    double lon(y, x) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude coordinate" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon" ;
    double lat(y, x) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude coordinate" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lat" ;
    double time(time) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
        time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
        time:units = "hours since 2010-1-1 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
    double time_bnds(time, bnds) ;
    double datum(time) ;
        datum:long_name = "Date and time in UTC" ;
        datum:units = "YYYYMMDDHH" ;
        datum:_FillValue = 9999. ;
        datum:missing_value = 9999. ;
    short temperature(time, y, x) ;
        temperature:standard_name = "air_temperature" ;
        temperature:long_name = "mean temperature at 2 m height" ;
        temperature:units = "degC" ;
        temperature:coordinates = "lat lon" ;
        temperature:add_offset = 0.f ;
        temperature:scale_factor = 0.1f ;
        temperature:_FillValue = 9999s ;
        temperature:missing_value = 9999s ;

// global attributes:
        :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 1.7.0 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
        :Conventions = "CF-1.4" ;
        :source = "surface and satellite observations, cosmo_090213_4.8_clm17" ;
        :institution = "Deutscher Wetterdienst" ;
        :title = "Temperature daily gridded dataset" ;
        :project_id = "TRY-advancement" ;
        :realization = "v1.0" ;
        :contact = "Stefan Kraehenmann, stefan.kraehenmann@dwd.de" ;
        :creation_date = "2016-01-23 06:07:57" ;
        :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.7.0 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ;
        :history = "Wed Jun 22 10:24:12 2016: ncatted -a history,global,d,c, TT_201001_daymean.nc temp.nc" ;
}
```

Typically, I see the netCDF file has **Lat** and **Long** axes in **1D**, e.g:

```
dimensions:
    lat = 360 ;
    lon = 720 ;
variables:

    float lat(lat) ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
    float lon(lon) ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
```

Anyone knows why the netCDF file **Lat** and **Long** axes in **2D**?

Answer (score 4):

2D Longitude and Latitude coordinates occur when the grid lines do not follow lines of constant latitude and longitude.  So any projected grid, rotated grid, or curvilinear grid, even if in geographic coordinates, will have 2D longitude and latitude coordinate variables.

Panoply should be able to work with these, as well as Python packages such as Xarray.  But you won't be able to use some of the nice tools to slice along 1D coordinates.

To extract data from a grid location nearest to a specified lon,lat point, for example, you need to write your own code, like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758480/xarray-select-nearest-lat-lon-with-multi-dimension-coordinates